# npx react-native run-android is not working in 0.61 version

Tags: react-native

Since today i having trouble to run project ..commandPrompt throwing an error like this..

```
E:\FirstProject>npx react-native run-android
error Unrecognized command "run-android".
info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
```

Answer (score 1):

just open two terminal consoles and run

```
react-native start
```

and in the other

```
react-native run-android
```

I think npx is only to create the init project with react native cli

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started